# The multiplication of a smooth function and a distribution

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f$ be a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $g$ be a distribution. Then $f\cdot g$ is a well defined distribution. Suppose 
$$
f\cdot g=\delta_0,
$$
where $\delta_0$ is a dirac function. Thus, can we say that
$$
\operatorname{supp}g\subset \{0\}\cup\{x:f(x)=0\}?
$$
In general, if $f\cdot g=h$, where $h$ is a distribution, then is it true that 
$\operatorname{supp}g\subset \operatorname{supp}h\cup \{x:f(x)=0\}$?

If we assume $g$ is a function, then it is trivial. But for $g$ is a distribution, I have no ideas.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true that $\operatorname{supp}g\subset \operatorname{supp}h\cup \{x:f(x)=0\}$. Recall that the complement of support of a distribution $T$ is the largest open set $U$ such that $T(\phi)=0$ for every test function $\phi$ with support in $U$.

So, the goal is to prove that $g(\phi)=0$ for every test function $\phi$ with support in $(\operatorname{supp}h)^c\cap \{x:f(x)\ne 0\}$. Let $\psi=\phi/f$; this is also a test function. Since $\psi$ is supported in $(\operatorname{supp}h)^c$, we have $h(\psi)=0$. But  $h(\psi)=g(f\psi)=g(\phi)$, done.